# How do I update the map marker without changing the zoom that the user has set?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, currentlocation

I have a Android App I am building that uses Google Maps with a location listener.  When the map first comes up I have the zoom set to 12 in the location listener, I am fairly new at Google Maps development so I was wondering how I can update the location without affecting the zoom once the user has pinched to change the zoom?  Below is my location listener.

```
/**
 *Mylocationlistener class will give the current GPS location 
 *with the help of Location Listener interface 
 */
private class Mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (location != null) {
            // ---Get current location latitude, longitude---

            Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLatitude() + "");
            Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLongitude() + "");
            currentLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            currentLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            Marker currentLocationMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Current Location"));
            // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng, 15));
            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12), 2000, null);
            if (!firstPass){
                currentLocationMarker.remove();
            }
            firstPass = false;
            Toast.makeText(MapViewActivity.this,"Latitude = "+
                    location.getLatitude() + "" +"Longitude = "+ location.getLongitude(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a local variable in your listener and use it to zoom only for the first location. The code would look like:

```
private class Mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {

   private boolean zoomed = false;

   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    if (location != null) {
        // ---Get current location latitude, longitude---

        Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLatitude() + "");
        Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLongitude() + "");
        currentLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        currentLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        Marker currentLocationMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Current Location"));
        // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng, 15));
        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        if (!zoomed) {
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12), 2000, null);
            zoomed = true;
        }                                       
        if (!firstPass){
            currentLocationMarker.remove();
        }
        firstPass = false;
        Toast.makeText(MapViewActivity.this,"Latitude = "+
                location.getLatitude() + "" +"Longitude = "+ location.getLongitude(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocationMarker.getPosition(), map.getCameraPosition().zoom));
```

Comment: you must be new.  This was answered years ago.